# F# interactive System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: exception, memory, f#, f#-interactive

F# interactive throws `System.OutOfMemoryException` when loading large objects into memory.

Exception is thrown at approximately 1.3 gigs.

Data set is 2.2 gigs, and loads fine in debugger mode.

Using VS2008 with April 2010 CTP

This is mostly a Java library that is being used via ikvmc, but if that were an issue, it shouldn't be running in the debugger either.

Answer (score 2):

What is the question?  What kind of data object are you loading (e.g. a large array of ints, or what)?  Might be better to email fsbugs (at) microsoft (dot) com.

Comment: It's a huge mix of all sorts of datatypes. I'll email them as you suggest

Answer (score 2):

The fsi.exe executable has a "32bit only" flag set.
The flag can be removed to allow fsi.exe to run as a 64 bit process.
http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/6369.aspx

From James at Microsoft